# Issue in editing in Tableviewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I created a table-viewer with two columns in it.first column name is "Fristname" and second column name "lastname". I added editor support to both the columns but i able to do edit/select only in the first column. In my second column not able to do editing/selecting. Don't know why some one please help me? Following is the code snippet.

```
   public class ViewPart1 extends ViewPart {

    public ViewPart1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private ResourceManager resourceManager = new LocalResourceManager(
            JFaceResources.getResources());

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        // re-use an existing image
        final Image image = FieldDecorationRegistry.getDefault()
                .getFieldDecoration(FieldDecorationRegistry.DEC_INFORMATION)
                .getImage();
        TableViewer tblView = new TableViewer(parent);

        final Table table = tblView.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true);

        TableViewerColumn fn = new TableViewerColumn(tblView, SWT.BORDER, 0);
        fn.getColumn().setWidth(150);
        fn.getColumn().setText("Firstname");
        fn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                Person p = (Person) element;
                return p.getFirstName();
            }

            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                return image;
            }
        });
        // fn.setEditingSupport(new EditColumn(tblView));

        fn = new TableViewerColumn(tblView, SWT.BORDER, 1);
        fn.getColumn().setWidth(150);
        fn.getColumn().setText("Last name");

        fn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                Person p = (Person) element;
                return p.getLastNAme();
            }

            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {

                return image;
            }
        });
        // fn.setEditingSupport(new EditColumn(tblView));

        tblView.setContentProvider(new QContentProvider());
        ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        list.add(new Person("a", "b"));
        list.add(new Person("C", "D"));
        tblView.setInput(list);
        tblView.refresh();

    }

    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Below EditColumn  class Code

```
public class EditColumn extends EditingSupport {
    private final TableViewer viewer;
    private final CellEditor editor;

    public EditColumn(TableViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer);
        this.viewer = viewer;
        this.editor = new TextCellEditor(viewer.getTable());

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
        System.out.println("can edit");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected CellEditor getCellEditor(Object element) {

        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getValue(Object element) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ((Person) element).getFirstName();
    }

    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object element, Object value) {
        ((Person) element).setFirstName(String.valueOf(value));
        viewer.update(element, null);

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `EditColumn`? How does it deal with the `canEdit` method?

Comment: @greg-449   that is customised Editorsupport class which i created by extending EditingSupport

Comment: @greg-449 i changed canEdit method to return true always

Comment: @greg-449 i have updted the EditColumn class code

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors here. You still haven't shown us the full table setup - what about setting the content provider and the input? You may be doing something wrong elsewhere in the table setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditColumn` class is always using the `getFirstName` and `setFirstName` methods of `Person` so although you can edit the last name column you are not using the correct values.

You need to use different `EditingSupport` classes for each column.

Comment: I tried it still the second column is non editable. Not only that i am not even able to select the cell. in case of first column even though i am not adding any editing support to it, i am able to select the cell but in case second column i am not able to select the cell.

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine for me with the editing support uncommented (macOS). I don't know of anything else to suggest.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.